# My script work perfectly on my computer, but not on another computer

Tags: powershell, batch-file, download

Well, this is my `batch` script:

```
@ECHO OFF
if not "%Minimizado%"=="" goto :Rodando
set Minimizado=true
start /min cmd /C "%~dpnx0"
goto :EOF

:Rodando
Ping www.google.nl -n 1 -w 1000
if errorlevel 1 (set internet=Nao Conectado) else (set internet=Conectado)
if %internet% == "Nao Conectado" (GOTO Rodando)
echo class Program { public static void Main() { >"%~dpn0.cs" echo using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient()) { >>"%~dpn0.cs" echo wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true; >>"%~dpn0.cs" echo wc.DownloadFile(@"http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/7/117FB25C-BB2D-41E1-B01E-0FEB0BC72C30/WindowsServer2003-KB968930-x86-ENG.exe", @"%~dpn0.installer.exe");}}} >>"%~dpn0.cs" "%systemroot%\microsoft.net\framework\v3.5\csc.exe" /out:"%~dpn0.exe" "%~dpn0.cs" "%~dpn0.exe" "%~dpn0.installer.exe"
powershell.exe -Command "& {if($PSversionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 3) {Invoke-WebRequest http://download1475.mediafire.com/dgmccvd5felg/cu6x9bzhx3hmz78/Teste.jpg -OutFile %~dpn0.png}}"
del %~dpn0.cs
START %~dpn0.png
```

First of all, it must run the `command prompt` minimized, and thats actually working. But it also must:

1. Check if the internet connection is ok
2. Check if `PowerShell 3.0` is already installed, if don't, download and
   install it
3. When `PowerShell` is installed, download an image
4. Delete the `.cs` file
5. Run the downloaded image

In my computer the batch runs perfectly, but in any other computer, simply don't work.
Can you guys please tell me whats wrong?

***(I don't speak english fluently, so please, forgive-me for any language mistake)***

Comment: need a little more than "it doesn't work" some details about the type of errors you're getting or whatever

Comment: Console output would be helpful. Perhaps it's a Java issue?

Comment: @ScottSosna I don't have much more to say, the console simply closes itself and don't do anything that i listed in the question. The only thing to say is that the '.cs' file is created and deleted, but i don't know if it will help.


***(I don't speak english fluently, so please, forgive-me for any language mistake)***

Comment: instead of open the `.bat` file with double click, try open using cmd by navigating the location of the `.bat` file and open it, so you can see the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
@echo off
if not "%Minimizado%"=="" goto Rodando
set "Minimizado=true"
start /min cmd /C "%~f0"
goto :EOF

:Rodando
%SystemRoot%\System32\ping.exe www.google.nl -n 1 -w 1000
if errorlevel 1 goto Rodando
echo class Program { public static void Main() {>"%~dpn0.cs"
echo using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient()) {>>"%~dpn0.cs"
echo wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;>>"%~dpn0.cs"
echo wc.DownloadFile(@"http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/7/117FB25C-BB2D-41E1-B01E-0FEB0BC72C30/WindowsServer2003-KB968930-x86-ENG.exe", @"%~dpn0.installer.exe");}}}>>"%~dpn0.cs"
"%systemroot%\microsoft.net\framework\v3.5\csc.exe" /out:"%~dpn0.exe" "%~dpn0.cs"
"%~dpn0.exe"
"%~dpn0.installer.exe"
powershell.exe -Command "& {if($PSversionTable.PSVersion.Major -ge 3) {Invoke-WebRequest http://download1475.mediafire.com/dgmccvd5felg/cu6x9bzhx3hmz78/Teste.jpg -OutFile %~dpn0.png}}"
del "%~dpn0.cs"
start "%~dpn0.png"
```

The line

```
if %internet% == "Nao Conectado" (GOTO Rodando)
```

results in a syntax error on execution if value of `internet` is `Nao Conectado` because of space in value and no double quotes used on left side of equation condition. And even with value `Conectado` the condition is always FALSE as a string without double quotes is compared case-sensitive with a string with double quotes.

And use always `set "variable=value"` for the reasons explained in answer on
[Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' on command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26388460/3074564)

On the last two lines double quotes are added as path to batch file could contain 1 or more spaces.

I have not checked the block creating the *.cs file, running installer and running PowerShell script.

Comment: SO would not let me edit your answer but the two commands for running `"%~dpn0.exe" "%~dpn0.installer.exe"` should each be on their own line. @DaMonki, I think the test for Minmizado will only work once because setlocal not present, but really should be a param on the 2nd invocation. the 1st exe does get created properly, but perhaps csc.exe is missing on the other machines. I am also not certain that link downloads powershell. It appears to download some `protectedroots registry key update` tool. Like other comments, output from your console and more echo/debug statements would be good.

Comment: @KoryGill The block with `Minimizado` works as designed. On double clicking the batch file this variable is not defined with a value. Therefore the environment variable `Minimizado` is created with value `true`. Then a new command process is started with a copy of current environment variables and executed there is once again the batch file. The current command process ends and in new command process running with minimized window the variable `Minimizado` is defined and has value `true` and therefore now the batch file is really processing.

Comment: Makes sense.  I was thinking of running it from same command line multiple times.

Comment: Well done my dear, it runs almost perfectly! (^-^). But... I need one last answer:  Have Windows 8 *PowerShell 3.0* installed by default? (If ***Yes*** , i can cut at least 7 lines of my script, and i also may say sorry to you guys that waste your time in that 7 lines. But if ***Not*** , i will need some more help...)

Comment: @DaMonki PowerShell 3.0 is installed and default on Windows 8.0 and PowerShell 4.0 is already default on Windows 8.1.